# Specify format of floats for tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set the format to two decimal numbers in a matplotlib subplot environment. Unfortunately, I do not have any idea how to solve this task.

To prevent using scientific notation on the y-axis I used `ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)` as you can see in my snippet below. I think my task should be solved by passing further options/arguments to the used formatter. However, I could not find any hint in matplotlib's documentation.

How can I set two decimal digits or none (both cases are needed)? I am not able to provide sample data, unfortunately.

---

-- SNIPPET --

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)

data = conv_air
x = range(0, len(data))

axarr[0].scatter(x, data)
axarr[0].set_ylabel('$T_\mathrm{air,2,2}$', size=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
axarr[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
axarr[0].tick_params(direction='out', labelsize=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[0].grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
axarr[0].grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)

data = conv_dryer
x = range(0, len(data))

axarr[1].scatter(x, data)
axarr[1].set_ylabel('$T_\mathrm{dryer,2,2}$', size=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
axarr[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
axarr[1].tick_params(direction='out', labelsize=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[1].grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
axarr[1].grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)

data = conv_lambda
x = range(0, len(data))

axarr[2].scatter(x, data)
axarr[2].set_xlabel('Iterationsschritte', size=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
axarr[2].set_ylabel('$\lambda$', size=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
axarr[2].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))
axarr[2].tick_params(direction='out', labelsize=FONT_SIZE)
axarr[2].grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
axarr[2].grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

See the relevant documentation in [general](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) and [specifically](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter)

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

[image]

Comment: Note: if you prefer to use new `.format()` style specifiers you can use the `StrMethodFormatter` mentioned on the [linked page](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter)

Comment: I'm plotting with `imshow` and this doesn't work for me. I've also tried `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.g'))` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929550/ticks-format-of-an-axis-in-matplotlib) but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: @airdas If you encounter a problem, please ask a new question about it, providing all the details and a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to use 2 different formats for ticks in the same axis? I'm inserting some extra tick and I'd like it as `.2f` but the original ticks I'd like `.1f`.

Comment: You're using `subplots` without argument. Does that mean it's additional to the `subplots(3)` that the questioner has? I'm guessing not, but if I insert a plot count in your code I get "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'yaxis'"

Comment: @VictorEijkhout See https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Comment: Even works without importing `FormatStrFormatter` separately. Its locates under `pyplot` 

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;` 
`ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))`

Comment: I had to use: ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) but it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is not a great way to do it because tick labels might repeat.

Comment: Since matplotlib 3.3 this also works with a format str: `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.2f}')`. As mentioned in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html), the value must be labeled as `x`.

Answer (score 55):

If you are directly working with matplotlib's pyplot (plt) and if you are more familiar with the new-style format string, you can try this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}')) # No decimal places
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}')) # 2 decimal places
```

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter):

> **class matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)**
>
> Use a new-style format string (as used by str.format()) to format the
>   tick.
>
> The field used for the value must be labeled x and the field used for
>   the position must be labeled pos.

Answer (score 34):

The answer above is probably the correct way to do it, but didn't work for me.

The hacky way that solved it for me was the following:

```
ax = <whatever your plot is> 
# get the current labels 
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
# Beat them into submission and set them back again
ax.set_xticklabels([str(round(float(label), 2)) for label in labels])
# Show the plot, and go home to family 
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should rather put it `[str(round(float(label), 2)) for label in labels if label!='']` or you are going to have trouble with empty labels.

Comment: I've also found that PyPlot responds best to beatings. Generally not worth asking nicely because experience has taught me that it's just going to mess around

Answer (score 11):

## format labels using lambda function

[image]
3x the same plot with differnt y-labeling

**Minimal example**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

fig, axs = mpl.pylab.subplots(1, 3)

xs = np.arange(10)
ys = 1 + xs ** 2 * 1e-3

axs[0].set_title('default y-labeling')
axs[0].scatter(xs, ys)
axs[1].set_title('custom y-labeling')
axs[1].scatter(xs, ys)
axs[2].set_title('x, pos arguments')
axs[2].scatter(xs, ys)


fmt = lambda x, pos: '1+ {:.0f}e-3'.format((x-1)*1e3, pos)
axs[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

fmt = lambda x, pos: 'x={:f}\npos={:f}'.format(x, pos)
axs[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))
```

You can also use 'real'-functions instead of lambdas, of course.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more what post is doing? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In matplotlib 3.1, you can also use [ticklabel_format](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html). To prevents scientific notation without offsets:

```
plt.gca().ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='plain', useOffset=False)
```