# Matplotlib. Place x and y axis inside the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

It seems weird that I cant find an answer to this question since this seems like something that is essential for a lot of plots, but **how can I create an x and y axis for my plot?**

This is a workaround that I use so far:

```
def f(x): return np.sin(x)
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x))
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x), x)
```

which produces:

[image]

What I would like is something like this:

[image]

What could I do to reproduce that? What I would like especially are the x and y axis numbering that is currently outside the plot (with matplotlib) to be on the x and y axis inside the plot, like on the image. Additionally I believe there should be an easier method to plot the x and y axis, instead of doing the hack that I do.

I've looked at a lot of [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) and can't find any example that contains what I want...

Comment: This is what you need to get started: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html

Comment: In case you are interested in tick labels like in the example you have shown (0, π/2, π, 3π/2, ...) then I suggest that you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53586826/2749397) by [Scott Centoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327973/scott-centoni).

Comment: Nice, that is indeed even closer to what I as expecting! Thank you