# How to change x-axis ticks into pi (π) terms with Sympy Plotting (Python 3)

Tags: python, sympy

I have this Fourier computation for n=3, n=5, and n=7. I want to make the x-axis have ticks in pi terms (from -4π to 4π with increment that can be adjusted for example π). I find on SoF that x-axis can be changed to π terms, but they all are using matplotlib to plot, this code of mine is using Sympy to plot.

The MWE:

```
#  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/fourier.html

from sympy import pi
import sympy as sm

x = sm.symbols("x")

# Computing Fourier Series
# This illustrates how truncating to the higher order gives better convergence.

g = x
s = sm.fourier_series(g, (x, -pi, pi))
print('')
print('Fourier series for f(x) = x over the interval (-π,π) : ')
sm.pretty_print(s)

s1 = s.truncate(n = 3)
s2 = s.truncate(n = 5)
s3 = s.truncate(n = 7)

print('')
print('Fourier series for f(x) = x over the interval (-π,π) with n=3 : ')
sm.pretty_print(s1)
print('')
print('Fourier series for f(x) = x over the interval (-π,π) with n=5 : ')
sm.pretty_print(s2)
print('')
print('Fourier series for f(x) = x over the interval (-π,π) with n=7 : ')
sm.pretty_print(s3)

p = sm.plot(g, s1, s2, s3, (x, -4*pi, 4*pi), show=False, legend=True)

p[0].line_color = 'g'
p[0].label = 'x'


p[1].line_color = 'r'
p[1].label = 'n=3'

p[2].line_color = 'b'
p[2].label = 'n=5'

p[3].line_color = 'cyan'
p[3].label = 'n=7'

p.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use [Sympy Plotting Backends](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) because it is a little bit easier to extract the axes from the plot.

After having the axes, you can use Matplotlib ways to change ticks to multiple of pi. [See this question for more ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642061/how-to-set-axis-ticks-in-multiples-of-pi-python-matplotlib).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from spb import *

r = (x, -4*pi, 4*pi)
p = graphics(
    line(g, r, "x", line_color="g"),
    line(s1, r, "n = 3", line_color="r"),
    line(s2, r, "n = 5", line_color="b"),
    line(s3, r, "n = 7", line_color="cyan"),
    show=False, grid=False
)
ax = p.ax
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(
   lambda val,pos: '{:.0g}$\pi$'.format(val/np.pi) if val !=0 else '0'
))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(base=np.pi))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'll probably implement an option to `spb` next week to make this easier.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot @Davide_sd, it will be helpful since x-axis ticks in pi terms or other terms often needed in Math, Physics and Engineering