# Scientific Notation in matplotlib inline plots in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

I am plotting values that are of order 10^-8 and I would like my inline plot in jupyter to output the yaxis ticks in that (scientific) notation. I tried :

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1E'))
```

as well as

```
plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0, -10))
```

and

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci')
```

but nothing seems to work.  What am I doing wrong? I have the following example:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

a=5*10**-8
b=3*10**-8
x=np.arange(0,10,0.01)

y=a*x+b

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(x,y)
# plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci')
# plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0, -10))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.0e'))
plt.show()
```

Any pointers would be helpful as I don't find anything on this, besides [ticks format of an axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929550/ticks-format-of-an-axis-in-matplotlib), [enter link description here](http://www.negative-probability.co.uk/blog/scientific-axis-labels-with-matplotlib-in-python/) or [Change x axes scale in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577665/change-x-axes-scale-in-matplotlib)
NOTE: If I comment out the lines with `import mpld3` and `mpld3.enable_notebook()` then it works but cannot interact with the plot... Is there some special treatment of matplotlib when plotting inline in jupyter?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a full [MCVE], and an image showing the current output to explain where it is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comment tom. I edited the question to include an example. Sorry for the "radio silence" until now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) to have a similar looking output.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticklabels(['10^-8','2*10^-8','3*10^-8','4*10^-8'])
```