# Matplotlib: axis ticks number format - engineering notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

**Background**

Axis ticks can be converted to scientific format as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929550/ticks-format-of-an-axis-in-matplotlib).

Numbers can be converted into engineering format, one at a time as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311148/print-number-in-engineering-format)

**Question**

How to format axis ticks in engineering notations i.e. order of magnitude is a multiple of 3.

Comment: You would need to write your own formatter being a mixture of the `ScalarFormatter` and the `EngFormatter`. Alternatively you can package this into a custom function and use a `FuncFormatter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around with the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) module, I came around with the following solution:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1 = np.linspace(-9, 9, 19)
data2 = 2.3 * 10**data1

yticks = 10**(np.linspace(-9, 9, 19))
yticklabels = [Decimal(y).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000001')).normalize().to_eng_string() for y in yticks]

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('10^k')
plt.plot(data1, data2, 'k.')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xticks(data1)
plt.yticks(yticks)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('10^k')
plt.plot(data1, data2, 'k.')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xticks(data1)
plt.yticks(yticks, yticklabels)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Please refer to the [accepted answer on your second linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311245/11089932): Exponents between `0` and `-6` are not converted to the desired format by definition/standard. Also, I needed to use the `quantize` method from `decimal`, too, because otherwise the outputted numbers would have had to many positions. (Remove the `quantize` part, and you'll see, what I mean.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to explain exactly what you mean by "engineering notation", but there is an [EngFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter), which automatically uses the SI unit prefixes (ie micro, milli, kilo, mega, etc.)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(0,1e6)
ticker = matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter(unit='')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker)
```

[image: resulting graph with engineering notation on y-axis]

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will show the axis ticks with order of magnitude such as 10**-3, 10**+3 and not the m, k notation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If one looks at [the source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.3/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L1312-L1460), they realize that [the solution proposed by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726120/2749397) [Diziet Asahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356000/diziet-asahi) can be easily modified to fulfill OP desires, as in the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(0,1e6)
ticker = EngFormatter(unit='')
############################################################################
ticker.ENG_PREFIXES =  {i:"10**%d"%i if i else "" for i in range(-24, 25,3)}
############################################################################
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ScalarFormatter (instead of EngFormatter) will do the job.