# Different precision on matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

My teacher said that in a graph I must label the axis like `0, 0.25, 0.5` not `0.00,0.25,0.50,...`.
I know how to label it like `0.00,0.25,0.50`  (`plt.yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,.25))`), however, I don't know how to plot the ticklabels with different precision.

I've tried to do it like

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(-2,2,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-2.25,2.25,1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1.5,2.5,1))
```

without avail.

Comment: Yes, I know he is wrong, but he is the one who corrects, so I must fitt to his rules, even they're not correct

Comment: there's nothing incorrect about what your teacher requested.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was already answered, for example here [Matplotlib: Specify format of floats for tick lables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/matplotlib-specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-lables). But you actually want to have another format than used in the referenced question.

So this code gives you your wished precision on the y axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-2, 2, 0.25))

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

You can define your wished precision in the String that you pass to FormatStrFormatter. In the above case it is "%g" which stands for the general format. This format removes insignificant trailing zeros. You could also pass other formats, like "%.1f" which would be a precision of one decimal place, whereas "%.3f" would be a precision of three decimal places. Those formats are explained in detail [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Did something change in the design of matplotlib? The `ax` in your code is a numpy array, so does not have a `yaxis`.

Comment: I don't think the behavior has changed. If you use `plt.subplots()` it will create only one subplot, so `ax` will be an `Axes` object (like in the code above). However, if you use something like `plt.subplots(1,2)` to create multiple subplots, then `ax` will be an array consisting of multiple `Axes` objects (that's what you observed). It's also documented: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Answer (score 7):

In order to set the ticks' positions at multiples of 0.25 you can use a `matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.25)`. You can then format the ticklabels using a `FuncFormatter` with a function that strips the zeros from the right of the numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

plt.plot([-1.5,0,1.5],[1,3,2])
ax=plt.gca()

f = lambda x,pos: str(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.25))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(f))
plt.show()
```

[image]