# Controlling label abbreviation matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting pretty straightforward bar graphs where the x values are large numbers. Matplotlib seems to handle this by using the last 2-3 numbers in the value on the plot and then in a 'legend' put the first x numbers. So in the example I am showing the first tick is representative of the number 8245540, 40 is used on the plot and 82455 is put in the legend.

Is there a way to control the way the numbers are abbreviated or simply use the full number when labeling the x axis?

Below is an example.

[image]

Comment: You need to format the x axis ticks. Label is the wrong parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
# plot here
pyplot.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
```

See this for more details: [Matplotlib: Specify format of floats for tick lables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/matplotlib-specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-lables)