# Axis values is not showing as in the DataFrame in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the Y-axis in the Graph with the Range in the Sum column.

```
total_by_year.plot(kind='bar' ,x='year',y='sum',rot=0, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

DataFrame output:

```
   year          sum
0  2010  42843534.38
1  2011  45349314.40
2  2012  35445927.76
3  2013         0.00
```

below is the Graph i am getting:
[image]

Comment: But the range of the y-axis does coincide with the range of the sum column?? The highest value in the sum column is 42843534.38 which is ~4.2e7 So, what exactly is not correct about the graph?

Comment: @AmosEgel Instead of showing the y axis as 0,1,2,3 i want to display them as in the dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: Specify format of floats for tick lables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/matplotlib-specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-lables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

y = total_by_year['sum']
ax = total_by_year.plot(kind='bar' ,x='year',y='sum',rot=0, legend=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you want just the scientific notation, remove `plt.yticks(y)`

Answer (score 0):

I see.

So exactly you want to change the axis format of the graph.
Maybe you could see [How do I change the format of the axis label in matplotlib
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362124/python-detect-the-same-object-on-two-images-and-selecting-them)

Or you could also do like that

`total_by_year.plot(kind='bar' ,x='year',y='sum',rot=0, legend=False,yticks=total_by_year["sum"])`

but it will be ugly. So I also recommend that you should capture the ax and revise the format of its.