# Python - Perceptually detect the same object on two images - and selecting them

Tags: python, algorithm, compare, diff, image-segmentation

I have some challenge and I try find any information, tips, examples which help me do that. First I looking many times google, and this forum with different ask but I don't found any this same task, algorithm. I try many commercial program to compare images, to find diffrent and common parts but all is don't do that good and smart.

I have some website with many different boxes, modules, elements etc. Now I do do first printscreen, save this image as web1.png.

Next step I change some boxes, elements on this website, for example I remove some block,  add new elements, move one of some module/part of website into another places.

Now I do next printscreen this website after last change and save as web2.png

And now it's the most important think what I want to get, do do.
I put this two images (web1.png and web2.png) for examples to some scripts on Python or another technology where smart algorithm to compare this two file and show, marked different or maybe only the first the same element on this two files. 
I think is the most big problem is defined what is exactly separated some block, module, many different elements on printscreen website and then find this same block on this next page and how marked this or maybe create next result png with this same element. I don't sure is possible to do that, whether there is a smart 
algorithm or way to do that. Thank you in advance for all the help and guidance.

**Here is images examples**

[image: Picture web1.png]
[image: Picture web2.png]

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/)?

Comment: No, I try this code, but this solution don't work good when you have many different places change or when you only remove some block to another place then show all picture was change, and is very many noise. I don't want to marked change places by black and white area. its not useful to show exactly what was change.  So I looking some solution more smart and search change no as whole picture and compare all picture but I need find solution to compare, find different after by identify some the same block and marked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to diff the HTML?

Comment: Maybe will be easier but data in are usually in screenshot png. I think the first step it find some algorithm to find the same "block" "part" on the two picture it would allow identity the same element on thesetwo images