# Python read csv file and store variables

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to python, so this should be a fairly easy question. I want to create a bar graph from a csv file. The file contains two columns with the headers "Latitude" and "TempAnom". I want to be able to read in the csv file and store the data as lat and tAnom. What is the best way to accomplish this?

| Latitude | TempAnom |
| --- | --- |
| -89 | 0.06997871 |
| -87 | 0.06997871 |

This is what I've tried so far, but I end up getting a KeyError: 'Latitude':

```
    filename='2016_tAnoms.csv'

    lat = []
    tAnom = []
    with open(filename,'r') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
      for row in csv_reader:
        lat.append(row['Latitude'])
        tAnom.append(row['TempAnom'])
```

Then I should be able to do the following to obtain my bar graph:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.bar(lat,tAnom)
    plt.title('2016 Temperature Anomalies by Latitude Band')
    plt.xlabel('Latitude')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature Anomaly (°C)')
    plt.show()
```

**Attempt 2:** Runs correctly, but graph is missing data

```
    filename='2016_tAnoms.csv'

    lat = []
    tAnom = []
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
      points = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      next(points)
      for row in points:
        lat.append(int(row[0]))
        tAnom.append(int(float(row[1])))
```

[Produced Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMHZi.png)
There should be data from -89 to 89, but there's a lot of blanks and the int(float(row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMHZi.png))) is covering the data to the nearest integer. I want to keep the decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to import csv and declare your variables as lists. Since plt will be able to use the list to display the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

lat = []
tAnon = []
```

From there you can go ahead and open the csv file you have and append your lists with the data in those columns.

```
with open('filename', 'r') as csvfile:
    points = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in points:
        lat.append(flaot(row[0]))
        tAnon.append(float(row[1]))
```

Then you can plot your points like you have above. check this out if you are still a bit confused on reading and writing csv. https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Comment: Sorry about that, try changing the appending tAnon to a float instead of an int. You may need to do the same for the lat append as well.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why my produced graph above contains a lot of missing blanks and seems to be rounding the values to the nearest tenth? Many of the values are 7-8 decimal places to the right of the decimal.

Comment: Without knowing too much about your data I can't help you much there. Found this, hope it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188910/4797904

Answer (score 0):

My bar graph was not displaying the way I wanted it, because I had my data converted to integers when they needed to be decimals. I added "from decimal import Decimal" and changed the int(float(row[1])) to Decimal(row[1]).

```
    from decimal import Decimal

    filename='2016_tAnoms.csv'

    lat = []
    tAnom = []
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
      points = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      next(points)
      for row in points:
        lat.append(int(row[0]))
        tAnom.append(Decimal(row[1]))
```